# Three-level accordion layout with table views in iOS with full auto-layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, accordion, ios-autolayout

I am planning to implement a very complex questionnaire accordion layout in iOS with the structure similar to the following:

`Root View
|_ UIScrollView
   |_ ContentView
      |_ UILabel
      |_ UITableView (cells = expandable questionnaire sections)
         |_ UIView (* table cell, view for a section)
            |_ UITableView (cells = questionnaire question groups)
               |_ UIView (** table cell, view for a question group)
                  |_ UITableView (cells = questionnaire questions)
                     |_ UIView (*** table cell, view for a question)
      |_ ImageView`

I would like my design to adhere to satisfy the following requirements:

- Auto Layout throughout with as little codebehind as possible.
- Each of the `UITableView`s can have a dynamic number of cells.
- Each of the `UITableView`'s cells can have dynamic height that can even change at runtime.
- Any increase in height at any level should push all parents to increase their height up to the `ContentView` of the topmost `UIScrollView`. The inner table views must not be scrollable, but rather stretch to fit all their children content.
- When the section view `*` is in the collapsed state, its content should hide (Hidden = true) and its height decreased.
- The `*`, `**`, and `***` views, besides any child tables, can also contain other helper views, such as section number, side lines, UI labels.

Is this even possible? I would appreciate any general advice on how to approach this.

I target iOS 9+.

Comment: This is 100% possible. `UITableView` is just a subclass of `UIScrollView`. `UIScrollView` with auto layout can handle all dynamic sizes without really any effort from you beyond the initial setup. And `UITableViewCell` is a subclass of `UIView` which is all that auto layout needs to size a scroll view's content. Putting this together simply requires a locked door, an unplugged phone, and total focus because it can start to get convoluted–but absolutely doable (sort of rather straight forward when you go piece by piece).

Comment: @iabuseservers can you recommend any resources / tutorials that might highlight the pitfalls and tricks related to my requirements (such as expanding throughout to the topmost level and collapsing when section is collapsed)?

Comment: Apple has documentation specifically for using `UIScrollView` with `auto layout` which is really good. They have a couple of, if I remember correctly, and everything you need to know is in them. For example, if I remember correctly, don't use any of the scroll view's anchors to determine the size of any of its content views. Use the scroll view's anchors to determine positioning but use `view` (for example) for determining sizing. When done properly, auto layout will handle all of the changes for you. You may need to disable and enable scrolling in some tables for a better UX.

Comment: And don't forget, the scroll view delegates are accessible from `UITableViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that everything is possible with autolayout with changing height of inner constraints by hooking their height constraint as IBOulets , but is is a heavy UI stuff it seems like an entire application is stacked in one screen , i advise to at least move **questionnaire tableview** to another screen

Comment: I agree, but such are our visual requirements which are not negotiable at this point of time.

Is changing the height constraints manually through outlets obligatory? Is there a way for auto layout to recalculate all heights automatically from bottom to top?

Comment: No , it's not obligatory he can use frame layout to accomplish that but when inner frame changes he must change every outer frame size  as frame doesn't push other ones automatically and that is the main difference between it and autolayout with layoutIfNeeded every outer changes